# Inserting a string after a certain character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to insert a string after a certain character using Ruby.

For example, if I have a line like the following:

```
(N D CGYRWIFGD2S7 0 1 N)(N D CGYCGYOVFBK0 0 N N)(ISA N N N CGYCG3FEXOIS N PUB NONE N N 0)(ISA N N N CGYCGYFGAOIS N PUB NONE N N 0)(ISA N N N CGYCG2FGAOIS N PUB NONE N N 0)(N D CGYCGYOVFBK1 0 N N)(N D CGYLOCFGA2S7 0 N N)(N D CGY01TFGD2S7 0 N N)(N D CGY01TCASUAL 0 N N)(N D CGYATTUSAOS7 0 1 N)(ISA N N N CGYAGTAD4OIS N PUB NONE 0 N 7)
```

I'd like to insert the html tag `<br />` after every closing bracket ")".

I guess I can use regex, but every line has different number of brackets. So this particular line can have 5, while other line can have 20.  With my limited knowledge of Ruby or in programming in general, I am seeking for help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
s.gsub(')', ')<br />')
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `gsub` to globally replace.

```
my_string.gsub(/\)/, ")<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, use split and join:

```
delim = ')'
s.split(delim).join(delim + '<br />')
```